# Problem with do-while loop (calculator) net.framework

Tags: c#, .net

my problem: i stuck in the do-while loop (choose an operator) even if i type in +, -, *, /.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rechner_mit_Loop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool b_Konv1;
            bool b_Konv2;
            bool b_Konv3;

            string s_Zahl1;
            string s_Zahl2;
            string s_Zahl3;
            string s_OP;
            string s_Ende;

            int i_Zahl1;
            int i_Zahl2;
            int i_Zahl3;
            int i_ZahlE;
            int i_ZahlD;

            do
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Erste Zahl eingeben!");
                    s_Zahl1 = Console.ReadLine();
                    b_Konv1 = int.TryParse(s_Zahl1, out i_Zahl1);
                }   while (!b_Konv1);

                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Operator wählen!");
                    s_OP = Console.ReadLine();
                }   while (s_OP != "+" || s_OP != "-" || s_OP != "*" || s_OP != "/");

                if  (s_OP == "Hallo")
                {
                    do
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Zweite Zahl eingeben!");
                            s_Zahl2 = Console.ReadLine();
                            b_Konv2 = int.TryParse(s_Zahl2, out i_Zahl2);
                        }   while (!b_Konv2);

                    } while (i_Zahl2 == 0);

                    i_ZahlD = i_Zahl1 / i_Zahl2;
                    Console.WriteLine(i_Zahl1 + "/" + i_Zahl2 + "=" + i_ZahlD);
                }
                else
                {
                    do
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Zweite Zahl eingeben!");
                        s_Zahl3 = Console.ReadLine();
                        b_Konv3 = int.TryParse(s_Zahl3, out i_Zahl3);
                    }   while (!b_Konv3);

                    switch (s_OP)
                    {
                        case "Addition":
                            Console.WriteLine("Addition");
                            i_ZahlE = i_Zahl1 + i_Zahl3;
                            Console.WriteLine(i_Zahl1 + "+" + i_Zahl3 + "=" + i_ZahlE);
                            break;

                        case "-":
                            Console.WriteLine("Subtraktion");
                            i_ZahlE = i_Zahl1 - i_Zahl3;
                            Console.WriteLine(i_Zahl1 + "-" + i_Zahl3 + "=" + i_ZahlE);
                            break;

                        case "*":
                            Console.WriteLine("Multiplikation");
                            i_ZahlE = i_Zahl1 * i_Zahl3;
                            Console.WriteLine(i_Zahl1 + "*" + i_Zahl3 + "=" + i_ZahlE);
                            break;
                    }                    
                }
                Console.WriteLine("ENDE eingeben um Rechner zu beenden!");
                s_Ende = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (s_Ende != "ENDE");


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple just do `while (s_OP != "+" && s_OP != "-" && s_OP != "*" && s_OP != "/")`

Otherwise it will always be true because your s_OP cannot be a +, -, * and /  at the same time